# How can I show a page depending of child button clicked with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to rewrite my app using SwiftUI only and I am having difficulty with the EnvironmentObject, trying to understand how it works…

I want to redirect my app users to the appropriate page at launch, depending on:

- if this is their first time
- if they have a login,
- if they want to start using without login

If it is the first time the app is launched, LocalStorage has no data so I present the app on a welcome page
I offer the choice of 2 buttons to click on:

- “New User” which redirect to the main page of the app and create a new user
- “Login” which present the login page to retrieve the last backup
  If the app has previously been launched, I present the main page straight away.

Now said, if I initiate my “currentPage” as “MainView” or “LoginView”, it works - but NOT if it is set as “WelcomeView”.
I presume the problem comes when the variable gets changed from a subview? I thought the use of @EnvironmentObject was the way to get around this…

Can someone explain to me how it works?

My various files are:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter,Never>()

    var currentPage: String = "WelcomeView" {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewRouter.currentPage == "WelcomeView" {
                WelcomeView()
            }
            else if viewRouter.currentPage == "MainView" {
                MainView()
            }
            else if viewRouter.currentPage == "LoginView" {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct WelcomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            // VStack { [some irrelevant extra code here] }
            VStack {
                    LoginButtons().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
            }
            // VStack { [some irrelevant extra code here] }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginButtons: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Button(action: {
                self.viewRouter.currentPage = "MainView"
            }) {
                Text("NEW USER")
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.viewRouter.currentPage = "LoginView"
            }) {
                Text("I ALREADY HAVE AN ACCOUNT")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Just want to check if it is working for now before implementing the appropriate Views...
            Button(action: {
                self.viewRouter.currentPage = "WelcomeView"
            }) {
                Text("BACK")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Just want to check if it is working for now before implementing the appropriate Views...
            Button(action: {
                self.viewRouter.currentPage = "WelcomeView"
            }) {
                Text("BACK")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Many Thanks in advance! :wink:

Comment: You can check that in the SceneDelegate aswell, and then present the correct View.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in your main view, the one that you are going to decide where to send your user, you could check for the app if it was lunched before or not, depending on that do whatever you want. Once you know how to do this, you can adapt to the other things. This is how you can check for it, again, in your main view router:

```
    init() {

        // Create initial Data if not data has been setup
        if (InitialAppSetup().initialDataLoaded == false) {
            InitialAppSetup().createInitialData()
        }

        // Onboarding screen
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didLaunchBefore") {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didLaunchBefore")
            currentPage = "onboardingView"

        } else {
            currentPage = "homeView"
        }
    }
```

The InitialAppSetup() class has a UserDefault which goes like this:

```
@Published var initialDataLoaded: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "InitialData") {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.initialDataLoaded, forKey: "InitialData")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Arturo for having taken the time to answer.  I am using the UserDefaults and the SceneDelegate for this part of the selection.  My problem is that my buttons on my main page does not redirect to the correct pages...

Comment: @cedric06nice yw, did it help?

Comment: Unfortunately not on my problem. However, I have finally found the solution without understanding why... maybe you could explain to me what I was doing wrong? I will post as a new answer to the original question here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... My 'mistake' was to add an extra ".environmentObject(ViewRouter())" when calling my subview "LoginButtons".

If I remove it, it works!..   **But why?!?**

```
struct WelcomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            // VStack { [some irrelevant extra code here] }
            VStack {
                    LoginButtons()
                       // -->     .environmentObject(ViewRouter())
            }
            // VStack { [some irrelevant extra code here] }
        }
    }
}
```